# How to perform indices query in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

What URL do you use to perform an indices query?

I see the following here, but what is the URL to do it too?
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/indices-query.html

The only way I know how to query in elastic search is with the URI:

```
http://localhost:9200/myindex
```

The issue I am having is I have multiple indexes with different documents
myindex1
myindex2
myindex3

and I want to be able to just perform any query on myindex1 and myindex2 (or just myindex2 and myindex3)

Is this possible? Also can you combine index query with QueryDSL like match_all query or Terms Query:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query.html

Please show an example of a sample URL, and what goes in the body of the request if possible so I can get an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using sense plugin you can write like this

```
 POST myindex1/_search
{
"query": {"match_all": {}}
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

You could try:

```
 curl http://localhost:9200/myindex1,myindex2/_search?q=*
```

Or

```
 curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/myindex1,myindex2/_search -d '{
    // your query here
 }'
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 6):

You could do this a couple of different ways.

1) With an indices query on `myindex1` and `myindex2` with a terms query on the `title` field.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "indices": {
      "indices": [
        "myindex1",
        "myindex2"
      ],
      "query": {
        "terms": {
          "title": [
            "foo",
            "bar"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

2) By specifying the indices you want to search in the URI (with the same exact terms query).

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/myindex1,myindex2/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "title": [
        "cookies",
        "cake"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

And yes, you can swap out the terms query for a match_all query (or any other query [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/), really) in either of the two examples.  Here's how you would do a match_all query in the second example:

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/myindex1,myindex2/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}'
```

Comment: indices: Query is deprecated in ElasticSearch 5

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing the elastic-head plugin. The 3rd tab on that interface has a query builder. You can select an index, build a query, and take a look at the dsl query it produces. That's a quick way to get up to speed on the dsl query syntax.

http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/